# scipy.optimize curve_fit() won't converge even with proper parameters

Tags: python, scipy

I'm having trouble trying to find the parameters of a gaussian curve fit.

The site https://mycurvefit.com/ provides a good answer fairly quickly. However, my implementation with python's curve_fit(), from the scipy.optimize library, is not providing good results (even when inputting the answers).

For instance, the equation I'm trying to fit is the following:

```
def gauss_func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-(x-b)**2/(2*c**2))
```

With input points:

```
x_main = np.array([19.748, 39.611, 59.465])
y_main = np.array([0.438160379, 0.008706677, 0.000160106])
```

where I want to find the parameters **a**, **b** and **c**.
From the mycurvefit website, I get the answers:

a = 4821416

b = -154.0293

c = 30.51661

Which fit nicely the given points. But when I try to run with curve_fit():

```
poptMain, pcovMain = curve_fit(gauss_func, x_main, y_main, p0=(1, -1, 1),sigma=np.array([1,1,1]))
```

I get the **"RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 800."** error.

What I tried:

- Changing the maxfev to other values, such as 5000, 10000, 100000 (no effect).
- Replacing the initial guess p0 to values closer to the mycurvefit answer (no effect) and common values such as [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], etc (no effect).

Even when inputting the answer, it still won't find the parameters! I have used this same code before with other similar cases, and it worked nicely. But this time it's not converging at all. What could I do to solve this?

Comment: Consider using a different optimizer (e.g. Nelder Meade vs Levenberg Marquardt)

Answer (score 0):

your problem is to try to fit an equation with three unknowns (a, b and c), with three points, this can have sometimes convergence issues. You need to give more values in the arrays you use to fit, the number of point use for fitting should be at least one more than the number of unknowns, in your case the minimum value will be 4 values, but is better to give more.

If not you can have problems as the one you have. For example using the values you have given for a b and c a have created some data, just by plotting this values you can see the point of your arrays are really in the edge of your curve, which indicates that the values of **a** **b** and **c** you have given are definitively not correct.

```py
import numpy as np


def gauss_func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-(x-b)**2/(2*c**2))

# create data using the values of a b and c you have give
x = np.linspace(-360, 60, 100)
# create y values and add random noise
y = gauss_func(x, 4821416, -154.0293, 30.51661) + np.random.normal(0, 100000, x.shape)

# fit the created data
poptMain, pcovMain = curve_fit(gauss_func, x, y, p0=(2000, -1, 1))

#plot data
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, label='created data')
plt.plot(x, gauss_func(x, *poptMain), label='fit created data')
plt.scatter(x_main, y_main, label='points given', color='r', zorder=3)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**NOTE** that the created data has been created with the values you have consider as true values:
a = 4821416; b = -154.0293 and c = 30.51661
[image]

Comment: "to fit an equation with three unknowns (a, b, and c), with three points, this will never work", not really. A quadratic equation is perfectly well-defined with three points. And the gaussian function is just an exponential version of a quadratic equation.
I know more values would be ideal, but it's not what I have in hand (I only have those 3 points). And the nonlinear gaussian curve is the one that best fits those points to the physical phenomena I need to analyze (I have done this same analysis for other '3 points', and they did well). For instance, polynomial fits are no good for this.

Comment: I agree that to mathematically fit a set of **m** observations with a model that is non-linear and has **n** unknown parameters **m ≥ n**, nevertheless you can have lot of uncertanty if your data point have for example lot of noise. Note  how the values given by  https://mycurvefit.com/ are far from reality

Comment: I agree with @LucasM.Uriarte. if you only have 3 data points, then in fact you do not (and can not) know that any function with 3 variable parameters will fit better than any other function with 3 variable parameters.  Many function forms will be able to have parameter values that perfectly match those data points.  You need m > n to be able to get any measure of uncertainty or any meaningful statistic to measure which model function fits better than another.

Answer (score 0):

With only 3 data points, getting a reliable fit to a function with 3 parameters will be very hard.  You will definitely not get a reliable estimate of uncertainties, as that requires more data points than variable parameters. In addition, exponential decay is really one of the most difficult forms for non-linear fitting to be able to solve reliably.

For sure, good initial values are  ***always*** important for non-linear least-squares.  And your initial values of `a=1, b=-1, c=1` are not good - in fact they are sort of terrible.  You would be able to see that if you plotted the data and your function evaluated with those values. If some other tool gave you better values, why are you not trying those values?

You are also running into the highly unfortunate behavior of `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` that it treats hitting its maximum number of function evaluations as a RuntimeError which would have to be caught as an Exception and then dealt with. That's unfortunate: with 8000 iterations, the solution may not be optimal, but it still could be reported (well, except that the `curve_fit` return value is so badly formed that it cannot give you additional information).

I might suggest using lmfit (disclosure, I am a lead author), which would not consider hitting the maximum number of function calls to be an exception, and be able to give a more complete fit report. That would look like this:

```
import numpy as np
import lmfit as lmf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def gauss_func(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-(x-b)**2/(2*c**2))

x_main = np.array([19.748, 39.611, 59.465])
y_main = np.array([0.438160379, 0.008706677, 0.000160106])

model = lmf.Model(gauss_func)
params = model.make_params(a=5000, b=-25, c=10)

result = model.fit(y_main, params, x=x_main)
print(result.fit_report())

plt.plot(x_main, y_main, label='data')
plt.plot(x_main, result.init_fit, label='inital')
plt.plot(x_main, result.best_fit, label='best fit')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

which will print out

```
[[Model]]
    Model(gauss_func)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 8000
    # data points      = 3
    # variables        = 3
    chi-square         = 7.9694e-09
    reduced chi-square = 7.9694e-09
    Akaike info crit   = -53.2387966
    Bayesian info crit = -55.9429598
    R-squared          = 0.99999994
##  Warning: uncertainties could not be estimated:
[[Variables]]
    a:  368.976235 (init = 5000)
    b: -57.3427447 (init = -25)
    c:  21.0033737 (init = 10)
```

and a plot like this:

[image]

which is probably not very different from what `curve_fit` would find.   But, of course, the uncertainties in the parameters cannot be found, and would be extremely high: a huge range of values for `a` and `b` would give decent fits.

Comment: I totally agree with Matt Newville multi exponential fits are very tricky, I have been using lmfit for several years and have been the main tool I used during my PhD. I have develop my own package dedicated for multiexponetial fits on top of it uisng the Minimizer class, Lmfit it is very intuitive and easy to use. It is a great library and I totally recommend it.  For multi-exponential fits I recommend if possible perfoming global fits on several decays to obtain more robust result.